# .NET equivalent of Ruby's begin/rescue/else

Tags: .net, ruby

Ruby has an else block that would go in a begin/rescue (try/catch for .NET folks)

```
begin
 #some code
rescue
 #oh noes! Catches errors like catch blocks in .NET
else
 #only executes when NO errors have occured
ensure
 #always executes - just like the finally in .NET
end
```

The code in the else block will only execute if no errors have been raised. Is there a construct in .NET that provides this functionality?

Comment: reminds me of `On Error Move Next`

Comment: How about a nested `try/catch`?

Comment: I'm looking for something out-of-the-box without having to build something. I could easily do this through an aspect but I want to know if there is a keyword.

Comment: What about code from else block goes after #some code? If no exception in #some code `#only executes when NO errors have occured` will execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, you can just list the code after `#some code`:

```
try
{
   // some code
   // Only executes when NO errors have occurred
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Catches errors
}
finally
{
    // Always executes
}
```

Any exception within `// some code` will prevent the "Only executes" section from occurring, as it will jump to the `catch` then `finally`.

Comment: Essentially your answer is that a specific keyword for "only if no errors" is unnecessary and as such, there is nothing in .NET to support it.

Comment: @DustinDavis Yes.  The way .NET's exception handling works, there is no need for an "only if no errors" block separate from the standard code block.

Comment: @DustinDavis This is true in ruby, too - the only real "advantage" of `else` is if you *expect* an exception to always occur, as the `else` block then becomes the exceptional statement.  In .NET, the guidelines state that exceptions should only be for exceptional circumstances, so having methods where you always expect an exception would be unusual (at best) - which leads to there not really being a need warranting a language feature.

Comment: As written in C#, if there is an exception in the `// Only executes when NO errors..` code it will be caught by the following `catch` - I don't know what happens if there is an exception in the corresponding code in Ruby, but I suspect not the same thing - so possibly this is not the exact equivalent.

Comment: @MiMo True - it'll bubble up in Ruby, I believe

Answer (score 1):

There are things with regards to exception handling that are possible in other languages, but not in C#. One such example is the [`fault` handler](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2004/09/15/introduction-to-msil-part-5-exception-handling.aspx) - in IL it's possible to define a handler that will only fire if there was an error.

The `fault` seems to be the opposite of what you want, but you could structure the logic such that some code will only execute in case an error occurs, regardless of how you handled the exception. .NET will generate a `try..fault` block for iterators. Bart De Smet once challenged the readers of his blog to try and simulate fault handler, you can read more about it [here](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/12/06/reader-challenge-fault-handlers-in-c.aspx).